# Spanish language chat rooms: enter, friend, and speak!

Tags: discusión, chat

[The chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=spanish.stackexchange.com) remain still unknown for most users here. The Stack Exchange sites have a shared chat room system that we all can use. We can create public or private rooms, but the thing is that there is a public room called [La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), created with the purpose of just chatting about the Spanish language or anything related with the Spanish Language site.

Leaving that room apart, let's add here any other public, subject-specific chat rooms you all create, in the hope that anybody here will be aware of that chat rooms.

Just remember to delete the chat rooms whenever they stop being useful.

Answer (score 3):

Chat rooms:

- [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) - A general-purpose chat room for the Spanish language and the site itself.
- [Translation Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf) - Chat room to talk about the [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) game.