# ¿Por qué está "La tertulia congelada"?

Tags: soporte, chat

Intenté acceder al chat de Stack Exchange Spanish Language  [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/la-tertulia) y no se puede escribir, no hay nadie y dice que está congelado. O sea, ¿no hay una sala de chat para este sitio? ¿Por qué cerraron ese? ¿Es porque todavía estamos en Beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una sala de chat se congela cuando no recibe mensajes durante unos días (creo que una semana).  Dado que esta sala llevaba muchos meses sin actividad, le pasó eso.
Acabo de descongelarla, así que está abierta a todos :)

El problema aquí es que la sala que mencionas se creó en 2011 ([fuente](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1792/la-tertulia#)) pero hace tiempo que no se usaba.

Hace un par de meses Carlos Alejo sugirió la idea de recuperar su uso (habló de ello en [Spanish language chat rooms: enter, friend, and speak!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2636/1674)) y en junio abrimos [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) pues no supe encontrar la primigenia.

Propongo seguir usando esta última, pues es la que tiene la actividad más reciente. Por ello, he vuelto a congelar la original para evitar más confusiones.

¡Nos vemos en el chat!

Comment: Gracias. Ya habia encontrado la otra, que si estaba activa. Deberia haber una sola, es muy confuso :\

Comment: @Theia tienes razón. Para evitar confusiones he congelado de nuevo la vieja. He actualizado mi respuesta. ¡Gracias por poner el foco en este tema!

Comment: @fedorqui en las búsquedas de google redirige a la congelada. Sugiero la descongeles, dejes un mensaje apuntando a la actual y la recongeles. Lo haría, pero no soy moderador :-D

Comment: @DGaleano qué bien visto. Acabo de hacerlo. Miré si hay posibilidad de juntar dos chats, pero al parecer no es posible. Habría sido lo óptimo. Gracias... y nos vemos en La Tertulia.